# How would I split a string by number of characters using getline?

Tags: c++, string, text-files, getline

Is there a way to take in a specified number of characters using cin or getline from a txt file and stop reading once the character limit is reached? I would like to read exactly 15 characters from a text file without stopping at any blank spaces or other delimiting characters.

```
ifstream inFile; 

inFile.open("file.txt"); 

string sname; 

//this is what I put at the moment but I don't believe it serves the purpose of what I'm looking for 
cin >> setw(15) >> sname;
```

I went through previously posted questions but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: You mean *besides* the obvious: a loop that reads N character pulls via `inFile.get` ?  If formatted extraction isn't the goal, then there is also `inFile.read` as an option, I suppose.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with `getline()` or `cin`,
but this should works:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("file.txt");

    std::string sname;
    sname.resize(15);
    inFile.read(&sname[0], 15 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. 32 bit char is still one byte.